# How to make a gaussian distribution in python considering mean. variance. skewness and kurtosis?

Tags: python, distribution, scipy

`np.random.normal(mean,sigma,size)` allows to create a gaussian distribution based only on mean and variance. I want to create a distribution based on `function_name(mean,sigma,skew,kurtosis,size)`.

I tried `scipy.stats.gengamma` but I don't understand how to use it. It takes 2 parameters - `a`,`c` and creates a distribution. But it is difficult to interpret for what values of `a` & `c`, the function will give a particular value of skewness and kurtosis.

Can anyone explain how to use `gengamma` or any other way to create such a distribution in python, even from scratch by writing mathematical equations?

Edit: By Gaussian, I mean that I want the distribution to be normal with some skewness or kurtosis as well. It need not be a standard normal distribution.

Comment: Reading your edit, I want to mention that every normal distribution has a skewness of $0$, a kurtosis of $3$, and an excess kurtosis of $0$. (I think scipy.stats.kurtosis calculates excess kurtosis.) If these are not the skewness, kurtosis, and excess kurtosis values of your distribution, your distribution is not normal. So what do you mean when you says you want a skewed normal distribution?

Answer (score 1):

The Gaussian distribution is fully described by its mean and variance.
Gaussians have fixed values for Skewness (0) and Kurtosis (3) - so you can't really change them if you have made the Gaussian assumption for your model.

Comment: Please check the edits. I am new to this statistics field. I am sorry if I confused between some terminologies.

Comment: Try the skewnorm on scipy - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skewnorm.html - Probably what you are looking for ?

Comment: This is looking similar to gengamma. Can you please explain how should I use these functions? Let's say if I want to have a skewness of 4 and kurtosis of -2. Then what should be my parameter values for any of these functions as they don't take the input of skewness and kurtosis explicitly?

Comment: skewnorm takes a real number  as a skewness parameter When a = 0 the distribution is identical to a normal distribution

Comment: Okay, but then how to take into account kurtosis with skewnorm. There has to be some clue that for some a, there is going to be x kurtosis.

Comment: Then perhaps you are looing for the non-central Student's t distribution - that takes four parameters: df (degrees of freedom) - for kurtosis (nature of tailedness), nct (for skewness), loc (mean) and scale (standard deviation) - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.nct.html

Comment: Do you know any relation between degrees of freedom and kurtosis as I think they are not exactly the same but do affect each other? Similarly between nct and skewness?

Comment: lower values of df (degrees of freedom) are associated with fatter tails (kurtosis). ZERO / Positive / Negative nct corresponds to zero / positive / negative skew around the mean